# Windows 10 - Pc not playing audio through headphones, stopped detecting headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones

Apologises if this is not the place to ask this, I've been trying to find a solution to this for about a week now and stumbled onto this site. If its the wrong place, simply tell me and ill try to find a correct site to post this.

I've been having problems with my Windows 10 pc in-regards to headphones. It does not want to detect them as headphones and instead as speakers. The first time this happened, I was able to solve the issue by using the first results I've gotten from google(disabling front audio jack detection, checking for sound driver updates, etc).

Its been 2 weeks since then, and the issue has suddenly started up again. I've checked the audio drivers, and they're the most up to date versions. I've tried unplugging and replugging the headphones in, restarting windows with the headphones plugged in, restarting windows with the headphones not plugged in, enabling and disabling the audio jack detection, plugging other pairs of headphones in, trying a USB and a 3.5MM audio headset, but nothing is working. Google has kept giving me the same 'solutions' constantly and I've ran out of ideas. If anyone can help me that would be fantastic.

Comment: Have you really tried an USB headset and that one still doesn't appear as an option? If so you have serious problem in the OS. Any USB audio device is, in practice, a different and independent (external) sound card. Even if your onboard sound chip was broken beyond repair, any USB audio device would work, you can even use one of those in a computer without any other sound system.